# On iOS only last sent data message is retrieved when the app back online

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

When I send via http V1 **several data messages** to my iOS app while **it is in background**, then when i **put back my app online** I receive only **the very last data message** in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

In Firebase cloud messaging legacy http all the data messages was queued and I could retrieve them by calling `setShouldEstablishDirectChannel` and listening `messagingDidReceiveMessage`

How in http V1 can I retrieve when the app is back online all data messages that was sent when the app was in background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Data message, Notification messages are always collapsible as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages:%7E:text=Notification%20messages%20are%20always%20collapsible:%7E:text=How%20to%20send-,Notification%20message,-FCM%20automatically%20displays). And it is expected that only the last notification is received. The same behavior is also set with APNS. You could check this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364493) to know more about the behavior of notifications with APNS.